# Could not auto-detect the runtime stack of your app - Azure webapp up

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html) on how to create a HTML web app within Azure

When I enter the `az webapp up` command I receive the error:

> Could not auto-detect the runtime stack of your app, see 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109470' for more information

The version of Azure CLI I'm running is:

```
azure-cli                         2.0.78 *

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                              2.0.78 *
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.4

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.16.0
```

Any help with this would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and it looks like there is a problem with static html site. Today version 2.0.79 was released and it supports an --html flag. At least my app is now working.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial guide you use the Azure Cloud Shell to deploy it, but as you know the CLI in the Cloud Shell is version 2.0.78 and it does not support the parameter `--html` and you also cannot upgrade the CLI in the Cloud Shell.

The parameter now is only supported in version 2.0.79. So the solution is to install the CLI in your own environment. Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to install the CLI then it will work well with the parameter `--html`.

Answer (score 0):

It just seems the issue is with the current directory from which the command is run.
It probably needs to detect files specific to a run-time stack before uploading the app; Such files, like the 'package.json' file for Node.js would on exist within the app's directory. So please try '**cd**' into the app's directory

Comment: Hi Ikenna. Did you mean "cd into" the app's directory?

Comment: Hi Joe, Yes, That's what I meant.